# Problema con Clase Abstracta sobre certificación OCA

Tags: java, clase-abstracta

!Buenas!

Estoy estudiando, y preparándome para la certificación OCA de Java 8. Hay una pregunta de ejemplo que no comprendo bien... La cual me dan este trozo de código:

```
abstract class Writer {
 public static void write() {
 System.out.println("Writing...");
 }
}
class Author extends Writer {
 public static void write() {
 System.out.println("Writing book");
 }
}
public class Programmer extends Writer {
 public static void write() {
 System.out.println("Writing code");
 }
 public static void main(String[] args) {
 Writer w = new Programmer();
 w.write();
 }
}
```

Y tengo que elegir la respuesta correcta de entre estas, para saber cual seria el resultado del programa:

> A) Writing... B) Writing book C) Writing code D) Compilation fails.

Según los resultados que aporta Oracle, la correcta seria la **A**.

Pero **¿Por que?**

Pensaba que era la **C**, pero al parecer no...

**EDITO**

> Contesto la **C**, por que en el `main` aunque se este creando un
>   objeto de clase `Writer`, se esta almacenando un tipo `Programmer`, y
>   por ello deberia de cojer el `Writing code`. Aunque es cierto que los
>   métodos no llevan `@override`, pero no sabia hasta que punto puede
>   llegar a influir.

Comment: Puedes agregar tus argumentos para la opción que ibas a elegir y de ese modo los demás te puedan ayudar de un modo más específico

Comment: **Creo** que la respuesta correcta es la **A** por que a menos que pongas un `@Override`en el metodo de la clase Programmer va a utliziar el `write()` de la clase padre.  Me guardo la pregunta en favoritos para ver si alguien aporta una buena respuesta!

Comment: Si los métodos no fueran "static" la salida sería "Writing code", pero como son "static" no se puede sobreescribir y obtendrías "Writing..." @Youshiro

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Al crear una instancia de `Programmer` y llamar el método `write()`,

```
 Writer w = new Programmer();
 w.write();
```

La clase `Programmer` extiende de la clase `Writer` la cual contiene una método estático, el cual en este caso no se puede sobrecargar, por lo tanto este será el mensaje a imprimir.

```
abstract class Writer {
    public static void write() {
        System.out.println("Writing...");
    }
}
```

Salida:

```
Writing...
```

Por lo tanto, **La respuesta es A)**

En el caso en el cual los métodos `write()` no fueran estáticos, la salida sería

```
Writing code
```

---

la clase Author no es usada :

```
class Author extends Writer {

    public static void write() {
        System.out.println("Writing book");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

La respuesta es la A porque si observas el método `write` es estático y al invocarlo con el objeto de tipo `Writer` llamas al método estático de la clase que seria el equivalente a escribir

```
Writer.write();
```

Answer (score 4):

A) Por que no se pueden sobrecargar métodos estáticos.

En Java el enlazado (binding) es la asociación entre la llamada de un método con el código de dicho método. Existen dos tipos de enlazado:

- Estático o Temprano, el cual se hace en tiempo de compilación. Aquí se enlazan los métodos estáticos, privados y finales.
- Dinámico o Tardío, el cual ocurre en tiempo de ejecución. Aquí se enlazan los métodos de instancia incluyendo los sobre escritos.

No puede ser C, por que no fallará la compilación, sin embargo emitiría un Warning diciendo que los métodos estáticos deben ser invocados de manera estática, es decir, desde la clase y no desde una instancia de clase.